# Many-to-many relationship in Objectify with strong consistency

Tags: java, google-app-engine, many-to-many, objectify, consistency

Being new to Google Cloud Datastore I would like to make sure that I am on a right track.

What I need:

- many-to-many relationship
- the relationship itself has to hold data describing the relation
- strong consistency is required both ways:

  - from user entity to all the data entities that this user has permissions to
  - from data entity to all the users that have permission to it

This is what I came up with:

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id String userId;
}

@Entity
public class PermissionIndex {
    @Id long id;
    @Parent Key<User> user;
    List<Ref<Permission>> permissions;
}

@Entity
public class Permission {
    @Id long id;
    boolean writePermission;
    boolean managePermission;
    @Load Ref<Data> data; //So that Data entities can be retrieved with strong
                          //consistency after looking up Permission entities
                          //for a specific User entity
    @Load Ref<User> user; //So that User entities can be retrieved with strong
                          //consistency after looking up Permission entities
                          //for a specific Data entity
}

@Entity 
public class DataIndex {
    @Id long id;
    @Parent Key<Data> data;
    List<Ref<Permission>> permissions;
}

@Enti.
public class Data {
    @Id String dataId;
    @Id String actualData;
}
```

If I understand right with this implementation the only way to filter Data Entities of a specific user is to get all Permission entities and filter Data entities in memory, am I right?

Is there a better way to implement it still fulfilling the requirements?

**UPDATE:**

In my understanding this implementation will allow me to implement logic that will retrieve data assuring strong consistency (having user id - ancestor query to retrieve all Permission entities and then using get_by_key to retrieve the Data entities).

I am wondering if I should approach it in a different way - since I do not have a lot of expierience with datastore/objectify.

Comment: I wonder why this question was downvoted. Please leave a comment explaining why you think it is not worth answering or how I can improve it.

Answer (score 3):

There's an important conceptual misunderstanding inherent to the question: Relationships are not strongly or eventually consistent. Queries are.

If you perform a get-by-key operation, the result will be strongly consistent. If you perform a non-ancestor filter query, the result will eventually consistent. Rephrasing this:

If you navigate your object graph using get-by-key operations, you will see strong consistency. If you navigate your object graph using non-ancestor query filters, you will see eventual consistency.

If you need strong consistency, structure your data so that your queries can be satisfied with get-by-key operations or with ancestor queries.

Comment: you are right - the description I provided might be misleading. What I meant is: I think that this implementations allow me to use means of retrieval that will assure strong consistency - getting a list of Permission entities using ancestor query and then using get_by_key to get Data entity. Having said that I am wondering if there is a better design that would allow for ways of data retrieval that will provide strong consistency.

Comment: It's hard to provide specific advice without knowing more about your problem domain, but usually "Permission" objects are naturally part of a User entity group; permissions don't usually change very often, or at least don't change more often than the User. The other advice I can offer is that strong consistency is often overrated. "Eventual" is usually pretty quick.

Comment: I would be happy to implement the logic that would work flawlessly with eventual consistency, but I need to implement synchronization between the server and remote devices (which might operate in offline mode) and eventual consistency might lead to discrepancies. The idea here is that user can register data and later share that data with other users (with selectable permissions for that specific data - something like sharing a photo on social site, but with distinct permission for each user). Don't get me wrong - I appreciate your input very much.It might turn out that I am on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic seems sound... but for a relational database.

This kind of logic doesn't hold true in the HRD that is the datastore. There are obviously ways to go around this, and you have figured them out with the way you described.

For consistency, your only chance is to use ancestor queries. The datastore is eventually consistent, only with "get_by_key" or with an ancestor query can you "force" consistency.

If you want something closer to SQL, maybe consider cloud GQL?

Comment: The implementation from the question is all about providing a way of retrieving the data while assuring strong consistency (restricting to get_by_key and ancestor queries - getting a list of Permission using ancestor query and then using get_by_keyto get Data). I have a lot of experience with SQL, but I want to achieve described result with Google Cloud Datastore. IMO this solution in now way seems sound for a relational database.